# "Would" means something different in the past than in the future?

Tags: meaning, grammar

If you use *would* to describe your action in the future, it means that you plan to do it. But if you use it to describe something in the past, it doesn't mean that in the past you planned to do it, it means you actually ***did*** it. Is that correct? For example:

> Whenever I would go there I would often
>   notice many suspicious things.

It has nothing to do with planning or intention, even back then in the past. It's not even the past tense form of the present form.

Am I right that the meaning changes?

Also, is there any difference at all with that sentence and this one?

> Whenever I went there I often noticed
>   many suspicious things.

Comment: Aside from the question, I would say there is a discordance between 'whenever' (meaning 'every time') and 'often'. These two cannot refer to the same thing. If they do not refer to the same thing, then 'many' should be removed as 'often' and 'many' either appear tautological or else create a meaning different to that intended.

Comment: But sometimes tautologies can be useful, right?

Comment: If you give me some specific examples, I might concede. However here, no; any two of the words 'whenever', 'often' or 'many' would be okay but having all three together creates a problem.

Comment: How about the second sentence? Could that mean that while at that place the speaker the speaker sometimes noticed many suspicious things, and that this happened often while there?

Comment: Yeah, what you end up with is: "I noticed many suspicious things then I noticed many suspicious things again and again while still there. This happened every time I went there."

Comment: I think you can see why 'many' and 'often' are not both needed. One is redundant - your choice which.

Comment: How about, "Time and time again, I would notice many people gathering at that house," and "Time and time again, I would notice many suspicious things."

Comment: Well, they're both okay because you're only using two of the adverbials. It's only when you added the third that it became a problem.

Comment: Isn't "time and time again" pretty similar to "whenever", with the only difference being the frequency of occurrences?

Comment: in these new examples, whether you say 'time and again' or 'whenever', it's ok (though with slightly different meanings). Point is, don't use both of them together. I think I've made that quite clear now.

Answer (score 4):

This usage of *would* is considered fairly casual, but the difference between your two examples is only in point of view: whether you're telling the story as your past self (*I would often notice)* or as your present self (*I often noticed)*. Another common application of *would* in a similar context is for habitual actions:

> I would go there every day after school when I was little.

Which is identical to:

> I used to go there every day after school when I was little.

Generally the version with *would* only makes sense if a time is specified, or at least understood from context. So this is valid:

> I remember when I was little. I would go to my grandma's every day after school.

But the second sentence by itself makes the listener wonder *when* the speaker is talking about. So generally speaking, these are identical:

> I used to…
>   *In the past,* I would…

Comment: +1, this is subtle and you have it right. One nit: the first sentence says “there’s no difference”, but of course, there is; you go on to explain the (slight) difference quite neatly.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff: Haha, good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The only nuance I can see is that of perspective.

To me, the second talks about the past from the perspective of the present (looking backwards), whereas the first talks about the past from the perspective of the past (looking forwards).

My 2c worth.