# "Did/would he eat something?"

Tags: grammar, tenses

Do both of the sentences have the same meaning?

> **Did** he eat something?
>
> **Would** he eat something?

I've heard *would* can also be used to refer to things that happened in the past.

Comment: Related: [“Would” means something different in the past than in the future?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/would-means-something-different-in-the-past-than-in-the-future)

Comment: Think about these alternates: "would I lie to you?" vs "did I lie to you?". The distinction is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first asks a question about the past. The second asks a question about the future on the assumption that certain conditions, unexpressed in your example, are fulfilled.

When *would* is used about past events or actions it does so to show that someone acted against advice (‘He would eat it when I told him not to’) or to describe something that was habitual (‘He would eat five burgers every day’).

Answer (score 2):

No, both the sentences DO NOT have the same meaning.

1. Did he eat something?
   This means, if the person really eat something. It does not matter whether he likes it or not.
2. Would he eat something?
   This means, it is upto a person whether he would like to eat something. His decision of eating is dependant upon his liking, his mood, his ability.

The first one if more casual, whereas the second one is more conditional.

Comment: *[upto](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upto)* is a "Common misspelling of up to" and *[dependant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependant)* an "Obsolete spelling of dependent" or "(US) Common misspelling of dependent" except in UK usage as a noun.